# Keras model not saving

Tags: keras

When I save my model in Keras via `model.save(filepath)` the file gets saved and there are no errors, although when I open the file this is what I get:

[image]

I've searched online and no one seems to have this problem. Also my Console has no details. Any ideas?

Comment: What did you use to open the file? Its an HDF5 file and seems you opened it with a text editor.

Comment: Your question's title doesn't match with your description.

Answer (score 3):

To load a model use this

```
from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model(filepath)
```

You can find more documentation [here](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model)

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me. model.save(...) saves 3 files with meta, index and data extensions and when I try to load_model, it says file not found.

Comment: With the code to reproduce th error we might be in a begter position to help :) can you post a new question?

Comment: thanks for response. I have the issue resolved now. I made some newbie error -- I was mixing tflearn and keras. Keras save & load works for me.

Answer (score 2):

To save model

```
# serialize model to JSON
model_json = model.to_json()
with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:             
     json_file.write(model_json) 

# serialize weights to HDF5
model.save_weights("model.h5")
print("Saved model to disk")
```

To load model

```
from keras.models import load_model
model.load_weights("model.h5")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a YouTube video that explains exactly what you're wanting to do: [Save and load a Keras model](https://youtu.be/7n1SpeudvAE)

There are three different saving methods that Keras makes available. These are described in the video link above (with examples), as well as below.

First, the reason you're receiving the error is because the HDF5 file is not readable with a text editor.

You used the correct `model.save(filepath)` function. This save function saves:

- The architecture of the model, allowing to re-create the model.
- The weights of the model.
- The training configuration (loss, optimizer).
- The state of the optimizer, allowing to resume training exactly where you left off.

To load this saved model, you would use the following:

```
    from keras.models import load_model
    new_model = load_model(filepath)
```

If you simply used `model.to_json()`, you would only be saving the architecture of the model. Additionally, if you used `model.save_weights()`, you would only be saving the weights of the model. With both of these alternative saving techniques, you would not be saving the training configuration (loss, optimizer), nor would you be saving the state of the optimizer.